# Getting stuck with backend in cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, admin

When I try to access to the address: localhost/chickenrainshop/admin/categories/index, the 404 error occurs. Can you guys tell me what mistakes I've made. (I'm using CakePHP 2.4). Thank you : )
My full code on GitHub: https://github.com/nhancs/chickenrainshop

I also changed the core.php: `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`
index is an admin method:

```
public function admin_index() {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    $this->paginate = [
         'order'         =>  ['created' => 'desc'],
         'limit'         =>  5,
         'recursive'     =>  0,
         'paramType'     =>  'querystring'
        ];
    $this->set('categories', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Comment: `404` means that the page is not existing

Comment: but what is wrong? this is a correct address

Comment: can you add the `index` function of the `categories` controller?

Comment: this is admin_index() function i've added above

Comment: i see.  so you don't have any `index` function?  what hapens when you go to `localhost/chickenrainshop/categories/admin_index`?

Comment: 404 error again, my full code here: https://github.com/nhancs/chickenrainshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note: This answer is related to the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34034291/2) of the question, before it was edited]

You are trying to open a "public" index page, but in your controller there is only a `admin_index` action defined.

Since you added the Routing.Prefix 'admin' in your `core.php` configuration, you have to

- either change the URL you are trying to open to localhost/chickenrainshop/admin/categories/index
- or add a public `index()` action in your categories controller

Comment: thank you but,  I also changed the core.php: `Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));` and try to access `localhost/chickenrainshop/admin/categories/index`, 404 error occur again bro

Comment: @NhanNguyen I'm cunfused now - Thanks for accepting my answer, but you are also saying it's still not working and you also changed your question so my answer is not related to the question anymore? Do you still have the problem or is it solved?

Comment: @NhanNguyen If the 404 still occurs, have you tried to set debug level in core.php to 2 and checked the error messages? Have you also checked the error log files in your Cake installation?